# How to run putty on a particular network adapter

Tags: ssh, ping, putty

I have a loopback adapter which uses SLIP to communicate  to a microcontroller. The issue I have is on Windows I dont know how to run putty on that particular network adapter. Does anyone know how to do this?
         Also I want to ping this particular loopback device and observe that packets are getting sent through it. I opened up wireshark and have a local adapter called bbbb. It has a physical mac address. how do I ping a particular IP address through this network adapter?

Answer (score 2):

You set up your IP addresses and routes such that the intended interface is the preferred route for the target device. (BTW that's NOT a loopback device)